# How to set full width image inside UIScrollView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I need to display large content in my `UIViewController` added in Storyboard so I added `UIScrollView` with constraints top, right, bottom, left:0 ( to make it full screen ).

In top of `UIScrollView` I need a square image with its width as device screen size, so I added `UIImageView` with constraints : aspect ratio->1:1, top:0, centre align in container, height : 100.
And below It there is a `UILabel` where I want to show large text. I am using Auto Layout.

1. Is there an option to do this in Storyboard ?
2. In swift I tried below

Connected Image in controller file as :

```
@IBOutlet weak var eventThumb: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // set image path from url ,it works
    eventThumb.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.event!.image)!)!) 

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    eventThumb.frame = CGRectMake( 0,  0,  screenSize.width,  screenSize.width)

}
```

I tried related answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455694/uiimageview-programmatically-in-swift) ,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345903/programmatically-change-the-height-and-width-of-a-uiimageview-xcode-swift) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773527/how-to-scale-a-uiimage-view-to-a-square-with-autolayout-inside-a-uiscrollview) but they not seem to working in my case.

I am new in swift and ios, am I doing something wrong in structure ?

Edit :
Image added

[image]

Comment: eventThumb.frame = CGRectMake( 0,  0,  screenSize.width,  screenSize.width). this code is not making the image full width same as screen size and I am getting same size image displayed in storyboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it in:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // your layout code goes here, AFTER the call to super
}
```

You forgot to call super before your code.

Comment: great answer! small typo: finish the function signature with "()" before the "{" and the func should be "override" +1

Answer (score 1):

You had tried to make the frame with following screen size

```
eventThumb.frame = CGRectMake( 0,  0,  screenSize.width,  screenSize.width)
```

Please crosscheck it with

```
eventThumb.frame = CGRectMake( 0,  0,  screenSize.width,  screenSize.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this Steps:

- First Remove all red lines here you can see in Image

[image]

- Now keep that line as it is, where you are setting a frame of Imageview

**Note:**

- I already tried this solution in swift & worked for me. I hope it will work for you.

**Edited:**

- As you mentioned you are using Auto layout, So no need to disable it. Just do 1 thing
- Put the line which you are setting up the frame of image view in this method: 
  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Thanks , But I am using Auto Layout in my app.and your solution seems to be using fixed width layout.

Comment: my concern is, since I am using Auto Layout in whole application, I am not getting the option you suggested.If I remove Auto Layout option from storyboard is will affect whole app which I don't want to use only for this option. Can I still do it with Auto Layout option selected ?

Comment: since I am using Auto Layout in whole application, I am not getting the option you suggested. I have added image in my question edit of what I am getting now.

Comment: I added   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        eventThumn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, screenSize.height  , screenSize.width)
    }
it set the image size on screen load. but when I scroll page ( as it is in scroll view ) it resets to old size